# one circuit or two

Tags: electrical

I am wiring a bathroom downstairs, it has one vanity light, one .9 amp fan, one 15 amp GFCI outlet. Can I run it all on one circuit with a 15 amp breaker in the main panel, using 14 gauge wire?

Answer (score 4):

The National Electrical Code now requires bathrooms to be served with a 20 amp branch circuit. This would require #12 wire. However, you can still use a 15 amp duplex GFCI receptacle and connect your other equipment.

Here is the code excerpt:

> **210.11(C)(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits.** In addition to the number of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at least one 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided to supply bathroom receptacle outlet(s). Such circuits shall have no other outlets.
>
> *Exception: Where the 20-ampere circuit supplies a single bathroom, outlets for other equipment within the same bathroom shall be permitted to be supplied in accordance with 210.23(A)(1) and (A)(2).*

Good luck and stay safe!